# Why does this value obtained from floatval() evaluate to false when compared against another number?

Tags: php, comparison, floating-point

See the test case below:

```
$val = floatval("336.00");
$result = 300*1.12;

header("content-type: text/plain");

echo "\$result = 300*1.12 which equals $result\n";
echo "\$val = floatval(\"336.00\") which equals $val\n";
echo "gettype(\$val) = ".gettype($val)."\n";
echo "gettype(\$result) = ".gettype($result)."\n";
echo "gettype(300*1.12) = ".gettype(300*1.12)."\n";
echo "gettype(floatval(\$result)) = ".gettype(floatval($result))."\n";

if ($result == 300*1.12) 
    echo "\$result == 300*1.12 is true\n";
else
    echo "\$result == 300*1.12 is false\n";

if ($result == $val) 
    echo "(\$result == \$val) \$result == 300*1.12 is true\n";
else
    echo "(\$result == \$val) \$result == 300*1.12 is false\n";
```

You'd think that the last if/else block would also show true, right? Not so! See the output from the same script:

```
$result = 300*1.12 which equals 336
$val = floatval("336.00") which equals 336
gettype($val) = double
gettype($result) = double
gettype(300*1.12) = double
gettype(floatval($result)) = double
$result == 300*1.12 is true
($result == $val) $result == 300*1.12 is false
```

What am I missing here? I've tried it on various version of PHP 5+ and they all produce the same output.

Comment: Floating-point comparison woes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [compare floats in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148937/compare-floats-in-php)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=floating+point+inaccuracy+[php]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Do not compare floating point numbers for equality](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php).

Answer (score 1):

If you read some about the floating-point arithmetic, you'll see that there's often a small error made during each operation. That means you cannot compare two float values for equality

```
$a == $b;
```

You can however check if the error is small enough for a particular precision:

```
abs($a - $b) < $eps;
```

`$eps` is dependant on the system you're using, you can read more about it on [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon). Of course, this only applies for one arithmetic operation. After performing several operations, you need to scale the epsilon appropriately.