# How to round up a value to get the right result in php

Tags: php

I want to create a simple voting program with php, but I get a problem in rounding out the results of the voting.

I have some values ​​from each of the existing topics, for example:

```
    $TotalVote = 13;

    $Value1 = 6;

    $Value2 = 4;

    $Value3 = 1;

    $Value4 = 1;

    $Value5 = 1;

    Echo 'Value 1:'. $Result1 = round ($value1 / $totalVote * 100);
    Echo '<br>';
    Echo 'Value 2:'. $Result2 = round ($value2 / $totalVote * 100);
    Echo '<br>';
    Echo 'Value 3:'. $Result3 = round ($value3 / $totalVote * 100);
    Echo '<br>';
    Echo 'Value 4:'. $Result4 = round ($value4 / $totalVote * 100);
    Echo '<br>';
    Echo 'Value 5:'. $Result5 = round ($value5 / $totalVote * 100);
    Echo '<br>';
    Echo 'Total Value:'. $TotalResult = $result1 + $result2 + $result3 + $result4 + $result5;`
```

After I add up all the rounding results, I get 101% results. I ever try to using ceil, but I get 102% resuluts.

How do I get 100% of the overall value exactly when everything is summed up?

Comment: your code will never work because wrong variable spellings and spaces between `$` and variable name like `$ result1 ` is invalid and `$ Value1 !==$ value1` and so on for others .Please correct it

Comment: you basically have this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6844441/1595977 . As a solution try to restrict to use 2 decimals.

Comment: if your values change then result may vary like some time you will get 115 also (for `$Value2 = 6;`). so what you want in that condition? again 100 as a final output?

Comment: I want to see a percentage of each value and when everything is summed, the result is 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code

```
$values = [6,4,1,1,1];
$total_vote = array_sum($values);
$total_result = 0;

foreach ($values as $index => $value) {
    $result = $value / $total_vote * 100;
    $total_result += $result;
    echo 'Value ' . ($index + 1) . ': ' . round($result) . '<br/>';
}

echo 'Total Value: ' . round($total_result);
```

And this code will produce the following output

```
Value 1: 46
Value 2: 31
Value 3: 8
Value 4: 8
Value 5: 8
Total Value: 100
```

Comment: But the values are not right in theory. You could change the output in the `foreach` into `echo 'Value ' . ($index + 1) . ': ' . round($result, 2) . '<br/>';`
If it helped you in any way than mark it please.

Answer (score 1):

That is what you get for rounding. Your logic makes no sense. Calling something the total value does not make it the total value, it's just the sum of the rounded values :-)

3 voters with values unique values gives 33% rounded for each group. That makes 99% total. Ceil() would give 34*3 = 102.

Answer (score 0):

I Edited this code defenitly work for you

```
<?php
 $totalVote = 13;

$value1 = 6;

$value2 = 4;

$value3 = 1;

$value4 = 1;

$value5 = 1;

Echo 'Value 1:'. $Result1 = ($value1 / $totalVote * 100);
Echo '<br>';
Echo 'Value 2:'. $Result2 = ($value2 / $totalVote * 100);
Echo '<br>';
Echo 'Value 3:'. $Result3 = ($value3 / $totalVote * 100);
Echo '<br>';
Echo 'Value 4:'. $Result4 = ($value4 / $totalVote * 100);
Echo '<br>';
Echo 'Value 5:'. $Result5 = ($value5 / $totalVote * 100);
Echo '<br>';
Echo 'Total Value:'. $totalVote = $Result1 + $Result2 + $Result3 + $Result4 + $Result5;
?>
```

Comment: this is hell. lot of mistake. please check once before posting any answer here:- https://eval.in/

Comment: I get 97% after try the code. I mean how to get 100%?

Comment: but this code will not work when values changed. this will work only in this one situation. check  @UfguFugullu  answer.It's the correct answer

Comment: Of course it works, but how to make each value display a percentage that has a round value and when summed, the result is 100%.

Comment: if u need the sum of rounded to be 100 there is no solution. by making it a bit complex u can get it. using ceil and floor functions in php

Comment: After using ceil in each value, I get total = 102% and after using floor, I get total = 97%. I need to get percentage that has a round value and after summed, the result is 100%.

Comment: you can use @UfguFugullu solution but the thing is the sum of values showed will exeed 100