# PHP microtime() accuracy (zeroes at the end)

Tags: php, time, unique, microtime

I've got two "similar" questions about microtime accuracy.

---

1) As was suggested in PHP online documentation, to get time in microseconds, I'm using a following code with microtime() function (looped):

```
<?php
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        list($usec, $sec) = explode(' ', microtime()); //split the microtime on space
        $usec = str_replace('0.', ' ', $usec); // remove the leading '0.' from usec
        echo date('YmdHis', $sec) .' '. $usec ."<br>"; 
    }
?>
```

I'm getting following results:

```
20140526135144 72254300
20140526135144 72255900
20140526135144 72256500
20140526135144 72257100
20140526135144 72257600
20140526135144 72258100
20140526135144 72258600
20140526135144 72259100
20140526135144 72259600
20140526135144 72260100
```

Micro means 1/100000 as far as I'm concerned. **So why does microtime return 8 integers for "micro" part, and the last two are always zeros?** Or I should play some lottery because I'm so happy :)?

---

2) Microtime is sometimes used to generate uniqid for example. But when I run:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    echo microtime()."<br>";
}
```

I'm getting:

```
0.21820300 1401105400
0.21821000 1401105400
0.21821100 1401105400
0.21821200 1401105400
0.21821300 1401105400
0.21821300 1401105400 // - the same as precursor
0.21821400 1401105400
0.21821500 1401105400
0.21821500 1401105400 // - the same as precursor
0.21821600 1401105400
```

How is that possible? My computer is not that fast as newer one. **Is this dangerous?** BTW I'm using additional "br" output, which makes the code run slower :P.

---

**UPDATE** According to comments, this is microdate(true).

```
1401106486.9772
1401106486.9772
1401106486.9772
1401106486.9772
1401106486.9772
1401106486.9772
1401106486.9772
1401106486.9772
1401106486.9772
1401106486.9772
```

To cite Zorba the Greek: Total catastrophy!

Comment: what about microtime(true)?

Comment: Haven't checked that out. But I will, thx for reply. Float implementation should be more accurate?

Comment: Take a look at update, please. Thx for comment once more!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should refer to the answer to this question [DECIMAL length for microtime(true)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14206159/decimal-length-for-microtimetrue) .

Basically microtime makes a system call and is therefore system dependant with a precision limited by the hardware.

As for the security issue, you should not use microtime as a unique id. Have a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php and try to use it with the more_entropy flag.

Comment: Very useful link. Thx for the lecture +1. I will wait with accept for more votes :).

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues here: The fact that the script is executed very fast and that "echo" outputs only the first few decimal points. This script gives more plausible results:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    echo number_format(microtime(true), 10, '.', '') . "\n";
    usleep(1000);
}
```

It outputs:

```
1401108499.0024349689
1401108499.0038080215
1401108499.0050148964
1401108499.0061480999
1401108499.0073280334
1401108499.0085520744
1401108499.0096609592
1401108499.0108559132
1401108499.0119121075
1401108499.0130879879
```

Comment: WOW! Echo outputs only few decimal points. I was living in a blissful ignorance. +1 from me, as it dispels my doubts. I will wait with accept, for more votes. Thx a lot!