# Error when subtracting two floating point values in PHP

Tags: php, math

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Compare floats in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148937/compare-floats-in-php)

I have the following piece of code:

```
$a = 1.49;
$b = 1.50;

echo $b - $a; // Outputs 0.01, which is ok

if (($b - $a) != 0.01) {
        echo "Not ok";
} else {
        echo "Ok";
}
```

The problem is that if statement echoes "Not ok", although the subtract result is 0.01.

Any idea why?

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: @Rapptz While that is generally the resource I would defer to, I'm not sure it applies here. EDIT: I am wrong.

Comment: @WaleedKhan True, floating point comparison is a tricky anyway. Not to mention this topic has been done several times over.

Comment: @Rapptz  explain what you mean  .. your reference does not offer any particular value here

Comment: I'd normally link to http://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/1331430 but this is PHP. Anyway, floating-point operations work similarly in any of these languages.

Answer (score 4):

The PHP [doc on floating point numbers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) shows how to compare them

> As noted in the warning above, testing floating point values for
>   equality is problematic, due to the way that they are represented
>   internally. However, there are ways to make comparisons of floating
>   point values that work around these limitations.
>
> To test floating point values for equality, an upper bound on the
>   relative error due to rounding is used. This value is known as the
>   machine epsilon, or unit roundoff, and is the smallest acceptable
>   difference in calculations.

```
<?php
// $a and $b are equal to 5 digits of precision.
$a = 1.23456789;
$b = 1.23456780;
$epsilon = 0.00001;

if(abs($a-$b) < $epsilon) {
    echo "true";
}
?>
```

---

Applied to your example:

```
$c = $b - $a;
$epsilon = 0.00001;

if (abs($a-$b-0.01) < $epsilon) {
        echo "Not ok";
} else {
        echo "Ok";
}
```

Outputs `OK`

Comment: I see, but the comparison must work both ways, so smaller, or greater.

Answer (score 3):

it's because some floating point operations. the result isn't exactly 0.01. your output is rounded by the system.

just try `var_dump(($b-$a)-0.01)`. this should be `float(8.673617379884E-18)`

a solution would be `if (round($b - $a,2) != 0.01)`