# Experiencing an issue with rounding

Tags: php, math, floating-point, precision

Why does `$x1` not equal `$z2`? I've tried `round()` as well as explicitly changing the precision to `8`. `$x1` should equal `$z2`

```
$x1 = 251.47267993;
$y1 = 3861.62758730;
$z1 = $x1 / $y1;

echo "{$x1} / {$y1} = {$z1}\n\n"; // ok looks good

$x2 = .06512090;
$y2 = 3861.62758730;
$z2 = $x2 * $y2;

echo "{$x2} x {$y2}  = {$z2}\n\n"; // hmm no - $z2 should be === to $x1

// why do these numbers NOT match? and how can I make them match?
// set some precision somewhere?
echo $x1 . " = " . $z2 . "\n";
```

More info:

```
_251.47267993_  /3861.62758730  =.06512090
.06512090     *3861.62758730  =_251.47266394_
251.47267993 - 251.47266394  = .00001599
```

Note that the 2 underlined numbers should be identical we divided then 
multiplied by the same number.  Should be inverses ... right ... but not when we 
don't have an infinite number of digits to play with - as is, they are not even 
close, they differ by "0.00001599"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compare floats in php](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3148937/1503018)

Comment: Unfortunately not a duplicate

Comment: They are not equal because that's how floating point arithmetic works. So - duplicate

Comment: The leading 7 digits (251.4726) coincide in both numbers, you can not expect more from the 32bit float type.

Comment: @LutzL: These are almost certainly double-precision floats, not single-precision.  The main source of error is from reusing the truncated output string for `z1` as the numeric literal for defining `x2`.

Comment: OK, I stand corrected. And yes, now that you say it, there are only 7 significant digits in x2, which causes the result also to have only at most 7 valid or significant digits.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what your purpose is, but why are you not doing this?

```
$x = 251.47267993;
$y = 3861.62758730;

$z1 = $x / $y;

$z2 = $z1 * $y;

echo $x . " = " . $z2 . "\n";
```

Equals everytime

Comment: Try with numbers that produce an irrational number...

Answer (score 1):

There is another problem: echoing float value. You have to increase your [precision](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.precision).

```
echo 1 / 3, PHP_EOL;      // 0.33333333333333
ini_set('precision', 60);
echo 1 / 3, PHP_EOL;      // 0.333333333333333314829616256247390992939472198486328125
```

Why are you trying to use value from screen but not from variable?

Answer (score 0):

In PHP built-in functions are not exactly the best for that kind of calculations. For example:
`echo (int) ((0.1 + 0.7) * 10);`
will output 7 instead of 8.

Anyways, 251.47267993 / 3861.62758730 is not 0.06512090. Depending on the computer architecture when doing this computing it will print different results. For me it printed 0.065120904138202, which is perfectly fine because the precision is about ~14 decimal digits in a floating point.

What you can do, is use BCMath library, which is documented really good in the php.net manual. For this particular situation, you could use:
`$z1 = bcdiv($x1, $y1, 200);`

instead of:
`$z1 = $x1 / $y1;`

And see that this number is not that small what you've been thinking. For more information, check this out [BCMath library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php).