# PHP function 'pow' weird result

Tags: php, if-statement, pow

I was working on a code and I could not understand the weird result I was getting.

```
<?php

    $a = 0.01;  
    $p = pow(0.1, 2); // result: 0.01

    if( $a < $p ){
        echo "true";
    }

?>
```

The result of this condition is always "true" while both of the variables have same value, but the result coming from `pow` is changing something internally. Seems like I would not be able to rely on this function. Would someone please help me figuring this out ?

Comment: if you swap the condition it won't be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its because of float inaccuracy,
take a look at answered question mentioned in comment by b0s3

> Read the red warning first
>   http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php. You must never
>   compare floats for equality. You should use the epsilon technique.
>
> For example:
>
> `if (abs($a-$b) < EPSILON) { … }` where EPSILON is constant representing
>   a very small number (you have to define it)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3149007/4998045

so you can trust `pow` function but you cant trust float comparsion

Comment: this looks good. In my case, it is working while having EPSILON value of 0.000000000000000001, if I decrease another zero, it won't give me correct result.

Comment: but watch out, with different operations with float comes different inaccuracy, so choose wisely your EPSILON value, because too small values should not work in other cases

Answer (score 1):

PHP Docs said:

> base raised to the power of exp. If both arguments are non-negative integers and the result can be represented as an integer, the result will be returned with integer type, otherwise it will be returned as a float.

Maybe you need to convert all to int or all to float.

```
if( (float)$a < (float)$p ){
    echo "true";
}
```

See it run:

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/2hv5-n2fw

Comment: true, but this is not the problem here

Comment: @Pepo_rasta that's the problem here. OP thinks that `pow` function is making internal changes, and it's true. The function returns the value with the type according to it. If you compare ints with floats, the problem is that OP said.

Comment: no, you have mistake in your fiddle dude, OP using `pow(0.1,2);` and you using `pow(0.01, 2);` which return 0.001, comparsion between int and float working slightly well... ps: how can you think, that 0.01 is returned as int?

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude it doesn't work.