# Php comparison integer with double

Tags: php

I got a problem with this script

```
 $total = 0;
    $expected_total =  1111;
    $i = [85.46,85.46,85.46,85.46,85.46,85.46,85.46,85.46,85.46,85.46,85.46,85.46,85.48];
    foreach ($i as $item) { $total += $item; }
    if($total != $expected_total) {
        echo json_encode([$total,$expected_total]);
    }
```

The problem is that at the end of the sum the $total should be equal to the $expected_total.
I thought about different number types, I printed the type of the two vars and I was right, one was *double* and the other was *integer*, so I converted the *integer* to *double*

```
$expected_total = 1111.00;
```

but the result is still the same.

The only solution that I could find was comparing the rappresentation of the two numbers, casting them to a string.

```
 if((string)$total != (string)$expected_total) {
        echo json_encode([$total,$expected_total]);
    }
```

But obviously this is kind of a hack.

Have you ever had a similar problem? How have you solved it?

PHP version : 5.5.9
Many Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148937/compare-floats-in-php and there's also a section of the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) dedicated to the topic, and showing how the comparison should be done (and it doesn't involve strings)

Comment: This is not only PHP problem. It is about representation of floating point numbers in memory.

Comment: The easiest way out is to store all the prices (it's prices, right?) in cents, so that you'll add and compare integers only.

Answer (score 3):

This is not only PHP problem. It is about representation of floating point numbers in memory. Floating numbers has limited precision. PHP uses [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point). Read carefully the [manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) and you will understand.

You can find in [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) code snippet of how to do it.

```
$a = 1.23456789;
$b = 1.23456780;
$epsilon = 0.00001; //very small number

if(abs($a-$b) < $epsilon) {
    echo "true";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check them as integers you could round both values.
You should change the if-statement to the following:

```
if(round($total) != round($expected_total)) {
  echo json_encode([$total,$expected_total]);
}
```

If you do it like this you will compare the rounded values, which will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

There is a big red label in the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php), that says:

> Floating point numbers have limited precision…
>
> So never trust floating number results to the last digit, and do not compare floating point numbers directly for equality. If higher precision is necessary, the [arbitrary precision math functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php) and [gmp functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.gmp.php) are available.

In this specific case, you could add the floating numbers using [`bcadd()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcadd.php) and compare the totals using [`bccomp()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bccomp.php). Both functions are provided by the [BC Math](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) extension:

```
foreach ($i as $item) { 
    $total = bcadd((string) $total, (string) $item, 2);
}
if (bccomp((string) $total, (string) $expected_total, 2) == 0) {
    echo json_encode([$total,$expected_total]);
}
```