# 2 exact values not equal to each other within if statement in php

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I have been getting information from the database which adds the cost of each item in a table.

Every is working 100% apart from when the cost is equal to a curtain sum it does not become equal, it is always greater.

For example if 30.02 == 30.02 it should become true, but its saying it is greater than.

Basically I have a foreach loop which is getting the cost of each invoice from an array which goes like this:

```
$i_array = array('2','3','4','5');
$i_total = 0;
$a_total = 0;
foreach($i_array as $i){ $i_total += floatval($i); }
```

Then I have a little bit of code which checks all invoices and if there are any it then adds them like this:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT cost FROM tablename WHERE id=id");
$query->execute(array(':id' => $_GET['id']));
while($fetch = $query->fetch()){
$a_total += floatval($fetch['cost']);
}
```

From there I do a simple if statement:

```
if($i_total > $a_total){ echo 'Too Much'; }
```

Now the problem is if i_total is lets say 30.02 and lets say the a_total is also 30.02 then it should be equal and it should not echo Too Much but its still echos Too Much.

If the i_total is lower or greater it is fine, just when its equal.

Anyone could shed some light on this it would be greatful :)

Comment: Float values are never equal.

Comment: Check out the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148937/compare-floats-in-php

Comment: And a manual http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php#language.types.float.comparison

Comment: Sorry guys I did not know it was a duplicate because I was searching for an hour and did not find anything on here... I simply did not search compare floats because I did not know about not being able to compare in a simple if statement for a float

Comment: @NikolayGanovski thank you so much, if you could put that as an answer I would gladly accept it to give you some XP on here

Answer (score 1):

You could try with [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php). Then you are comparing `string` values instead of `float`.