# Laravel IF statement not working while inside FOR loop

Tags: php, laravel

We are looking to increment the `<option>`  within a `<select>` input type. If the option value `$AccountExecutive->COMMISSION_RATE` is `$Rate`, the `<option>` should be selected.

I should note that `$AccountExecutive->COMMISSION_RATE` is a decimal (0.5000).

We have successfully done this in standard PHP but we would like it to stay in Laravel.

```
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="AE_COMMISSION_RATE">Commission Rate</label>
                  <select class="form-control" id="AE_COMMISSION_RATE" name="AE_COMMISSION_RATE">
                    <option value="0">Please enter a Value..</option>
                  @for($Rates = .05; $Rates < 1.05; $Rates += .05)
                    @if($AccountExecutive->COMMISSION_RATE == $Rates)
                      <option value="{{ $Rates }}" selected>{{ $Rates * 100 }}% </option>
                    @else
                      <option value="{{ $Rates }}">{{ $Rates * 100 }}%</option>
                    @endif
                  @endfor
                  </select>
              </div>
```

Comment: What does the output look like?

Comment: @Birdman $AccountExecutive->COMMISSION_RATE = 0.5000

Comment: Comparing float values does not work this way.

Comment: When comparing float values it is not recommended to do a ==, you need to come up with a way to accept tolerance, sometimes exact values in two decimals are not the same when comparing the full bits of the floats

Comment: Topic to start with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148937/compare-floats-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just work with integers. Let `$Rates` is a percent value, not fractional.

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="AE_COMMISSION_RATE">Commission Rate</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="AE_COMMISSION_RATE" name="AE_COMMISSION_RATE">
        <option value="0">Please enter a Value..</option>
        @for($Rates = 5; $Rates < 105; $Rates += 5)
        @if(intval($AccountExecutive->COMMISSION_RATE * 100) === $Rates)
            <option value="{{ $Rates / 100 }}" selected>{{ $Rates }}% </option>
        @else
            <option value="{{ $Rates / 100 }}">{{ $Rates }}%</option>
        @endif
    @endfor
    </select>
</div>
```