# Function to check if number is multiple of another (including decimals)

Tags: php, cakephp

Hello I am trying to build a function to check if a number is multiple of another:

What I am trying to get:

```
my_function (10,2) = true
my_function (8,3) = false
my_function (9.5,0.5) = true
my_function (6,1.5) = true
my_function (1.1,0.1) = true
```

My function is:

```
//Check if $number1 is a multiple of $number2
function my_function( $number1, $number2 ){
    $_number = $number1 / $number2;  

    if( $_number == floor( $_number ) ) :
        return true;
    else :
        return false;
    endif;
}
```

It is working like a charm, except that for some reason when there are values 3,7,11, etc it is returning false when it should clearly return true:

```
my_function (5.4,0.3) = false (it is retruning false, it should be true!)
my_function (7.7,0.7) = false (it is retruning false, it should be true!)
```

Any idea why? Is it a compiler error? I run out of ideas. Thank you

Comment: You should try printing out the result of `floor($_number) - $_number` It is possible that the floats are not exactly equal after the division and have something like `5.4 / 0.3 = 18.00000000000012`

Comment: I echo'd $_number and floor( $_number ) and both are the same. Let me try printing floor($_number) - $_number

Comment: @EastonBornemeier you are right. After printing out `floor($_number) - $_number` the floats are not the same. What could i do?

Comment: Start with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148937/compare-floats-in-php

Comment: @u_mulder Thank you! it is working now! :D

Comment: [should I do float comporison](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4915462/6521116)

Comment: This whole function can be replaced with: `return fmod($number1, $number2) < 0.00001`

Comment: The above is the best answer, the marked answer will not always work *see my comment*

Comment: This is not about comparing float numbers, question is to know if 1st number is integer multiple of 2nd number or not.

Comment: @anubhava what's your point? If the remainder of the division is 0, I am pretty sure that the first number is integer multiple of the 2nd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the resulting type of `floor` is double and `$_number` is also double, the safest way it to have a relative comparison `<` instead of absolute comparison.

Floating precision might vary. Thus, this is the safest way:

```
if (abs(floor( $_number ) - $_number) < 0.00001) {
    return true;
}

return false;
```

Comment: This is dangerous and I beleive will still cause erorrs. What if the value of number is slightly below the desired number? i.e. `4/.5 = 7.999999999` this result will make it so it floors to 7, and then it will return false

Comment: @karlosuccess You may be interested in fmod later, check it out: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php

Comment: ok so if I use `fmod`, I still have to use `fmod( $number1, $number2 ) < 0.00001`, because even `fmod` also returns tiny decimals. So what is the answer then?

Comment: @karlosuccess my area isn't math, so i can't help with the floating precision problem. I've asked some friends and they recommended me to check the BC Math extension, and linked me this: http://floating-point-gui.de/ and this: http://floating-point-gui.de/languages/php/

Comment: @karlosuccess Yes, use `fmod( $number1, $number2 ) < 0.00001`