# PHP Rounding Float Values With Ceil And Result Comparison Is Not As It Must Be

Tags: php, numbers, comparison, rounding, var-dump

I have a PHP function as

```
function func(){

    function round_up($value, $decPlaces) {
        return ceil($value * pow(10, $decPlaces)) / pow(10, $decPlaces);
    }

    $a=21.31;
    $b=2;
    $c=10.64;
    $d=0.03;

    $xxx=$a;
    $yyy=round_up($b*$c,2)+round_up($d,2);
    $zzz=($xxx===$yyy);

    var_dump($xxx,$yyy,$zzz);
}
```

This function outputs

> float(21.31) float(21.31) bool(false)

It seems xxx equal to yyy but why zzz is false? Where is the problem in this function and result?

Comment: See: http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change last line to this to see difference:

var_dump(number_format($xxx, 20), number_format($yyy, 20), $zzz);

Here are some helpful info about the problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3148991/4180451  https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php
https://andy-carter.com/blog/don-t-trust-php-floating-point-numbers-when-equating

and many more... :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your gold answer. This information is very important for financial operations as money or etc.