# PHP value comparison wrong despite correct typing

Tags: php, casting, comparison, variable-types

This piece of code:

```
$total=$o->cart->getTotalSum();
$subTotal=$o->cart->getSubTotal();

if(floatval($r['sum_total']) != floatval($total) ||
   floatval($r['sum_sub']) != floatval($subTotal)) {
      echo 'Differs on #' . $r['id'];
      echo 'Total: ' . $total . ' / ' . $r['sum_total'];
      echo 'Sub: ' . $subTotal . ' / ' . $r['sum_sub'];
   }
```

Gives me this output:

```
Differs on #697
Total: 19.6 / 19.6
Sub: 19.6 / 19.6
```

Why? How is that even possible?

I make sure that all values compared are of type float, so no strings could have slipped in.

I must be missing something.

My apologies for not providing really reproducible code, but i wouldn't know how in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you do it like this they should be the same. But note that a characteristic of floating-point values is that calculations which
>   seem to result in the same value do not need to actually be identical.
>   So if `$a` is a literal `.17` and `$b` arrives there through a calculation
>   it can well be that they are different, albeit both display the same
>   value.
>
> Usually you never compare floating-point values for equality like
>   this, you need to use a smallest acceptable difference:
>
> `if (abs(($a-$b)/$b) < 0.00001) {   echo "same"; }` Something like that.

I think someone else had the exact same problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3148991/2725502

Comment: Vote to close as duplicate, don't copy answers.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to that question, i was unable to find it an appropriate one for my problem while searching. Please remove your answer so i can delete my question. It's useless in the network given the circumstances