# Amount and comparison do not match

Tags: php

Amount does not match value

Tested. Opnserver.

> PHP 7.1.12 (cli) (built: Nov 23 2017 04:34:08) ( ZTS MSVC14 (Visual
>   C++ 2015) x86 )

Or in tested http://www.writephponline.com/

```php
    $loc=6084.87+7764.25+403.88+149.0;
    var_dump($loc);
    $summI=(float)"14402.00";
    var_dump($summI==$loc);
```

Comment: One way to workaround the issue is to use `number_format()`: https://3v4l.org/q7YMR

Comment: Comparing floats with == operator is not the right way. use abs($a-$b) <  0.000001 )(or PHP_FLOAT_EPSILON  constant). see for example:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148937/compare-floats-in-php

Comment: Thanks. Official documentation [link](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.float.php)