# FMOD in PHP results not being seen as equal to their float equivalent

Tags: php, modulo, fmod, triple-equals

So I understand that `FMOD` gives some wacky answers sometimes because its sort of approximate.
But even given that I'm struggling to utilize the answers it throws up later-on in the code.

For instance, `fmod(16,1.6)` gives us 1.6 rather than 0, that's fine. In the following code, echoing `$goodfit` prints 1.6 but hurray doesn't print.

```php
$getLength = 16;
$goodFit = fmod($getLength, 1.6);
echo $goodFit;
if ($goodFit === 1.6){
    echo hurray;
}
```

I've tried double equation signs instead of triple incase it was a data type problem and I've tried rounding the `$goodfit` equation to one decimal place.

All seems a little odd.
I'm just trying to make a bit of code that triggers if a division was exact.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare floats in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148937/compare-floats-in-php)

Comment: This does! thank you so much.