# log(1000, 100) does not return 1.5

Tags: php, logarithm

When I run this code:

```php
$value = log(1000, 100);

echo $value;

if ($value == 1.5) {
    echo 'Equal';
} else {
    echo 'Not Equal';
}
```

I see `1.5Not Equal`. This is very strange because `log(1000, 100)` does return `1.5`, but it does not match the if statement.

Why does PHP do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare floats in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148937/compare-floats-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you `var_dump` your `$value` you will see the result is `float(1.4999999999999998)` and that is not equal to `1.5`, you need to use round like:

```
$value = round(log(1000, 100), 1);

if ($value == 1.5) {
    echo 'Equal';
} else {
    echo 'Not Equal';
}
```

[Here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f8fe9e7fb7a39bf920439dd81053244eaca329be) you can see result.

Reference:

- [round](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php)
- [see Floating point precision](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php)

Comment: But why does PHP do this then? Because log(1000, 100) is clearly 1.5 and not 1.4999999999999998

Comment: See second reference.