# Check decimal numbers in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have decimal numbers like this `0.00651536` and I am unable to validating this number to see if its greater than other decimal number (e.g: `0.00651537`) or not!

here is an example:

```
//$request->input('price') = 0.00651537
//$product->price = 0.00651536

if($request->input('price') > $product->price) {
  // my input is greater than product price
} else {
  // my input is not greater than product price
}
```

**Issue: (Update)**

As my `$product->price` is decimal starting with `0.` it just keep looking to that `0` and does not validate rest of it while my input number difference with product price is in decimals.

**How can I validate my numbers?**

> PS: These are just sample numbers therefore decimals could be shorter or longer (don't go with this example length)

Comment: Your logic is working, so what seems to be the issue???

Comment: @Anuga this if statement has else part and it always return else part unless i input an integer (not decimal number)

Comment: My read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148937/compare-floats-in-php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare floats in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148937/compare-floats-in-php)

Comment: @Justinas no, I've just tried `floatval( (string) xxxx)` didn't work

Comment: This is your code written to be executable: https://3v4l.org/m9IhC Clearly there's something else going on you haven't told us about.

Comment: What is the output when you `var_dump` both `$request->input('price')` and `$product->price`?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware this is what I'm getting in my test `{"input":0.00651545,"product":0.00651536,"result":false}`

Comment: @RJK My values are strings so I added `(float)` in front of each one like this `(float)$request->input('price')` and `(float)$product->price`

Comment: To really be able to help you we would need a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but you already know that. Why can't you provide one?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware It somehow just worked!!! i will retry this later if it still gave error I make sure to share with you controller function completely. thanks again (let see if it keeps working!)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried converting it to float?

You can try something like:

```
   if(floatval($request->input('price')) > floatval( $product->price)) {
  // my input is greater than product price
} else {
  // my input is not greater than product price
}
```

Comment: Yes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74887112/check-decimal-numbers-in-laravel/74887674#comment132157524_74887112