Php if statement issue. Returning wrong result
I have this code that is returning incorrect value.
The result is '7 price3' but it is wrong. 7 should fall on second if statement since $value is greater than 5 and less than or equal to 7. You can try on your php editor and it will return on the third if statement.
$price = 100;
$requestprice = 93;

$value = (($price - $requestprice) / $price) * 100;

if ($value <= 5) {
    echo $value . ' price 1';
} else if ($value > 5 && $value <= 7) {
    echo $value . ' price 2';
} else if ($value > 7 && $value <= 10) {
    echo $value . ' price 3';
}

Tried to run the code on any php editor and still got the wrong result

$value is a float value, convert it to an integer for accurate comparisons. Also, you don't need repeated comparisons. See also
<?php

$price = 100;
$requestprice = 93;

$value = intval((($price - $requestprice) / $price) * 100);

if ($value <= 5) {
    echo $value . ' price 1';
} else if ($value <= 7) {
    echo $value . ' price 2';
} else if ($value <= 10) {// or skip this if condition
    echo $value . ' price 3';
}

Online Demo

intval() truncates, so it's definitely not the right way to do it.

@Olivier yes you are right, it is now returning whole number. I still need to keep the decimal point

@Olivier Integer comparisons in OP's code does make me assume that OP doesn't care about the decimal points(unless said so, which he did just now).

@iAnnskie In that case, you can make another temp variable for displaying and use the integer converted variable only for comparisons. Hope you know some basic programming at least.

@nice_dev thank you, actually i don't need to convert it to integer since decimal points are needed for comparison, since $value result will vary on $requestprice and $price value. Is there a way that it will go to second if without converting it to integer?

@iAnnskie If you need the decimal points while comparison itself, then a safer way is to keep some epsilon value threshold during comparison in the if statements. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148937/compare-floats-in-php

@nice_dev yes adding this code $value = number_format($value, 2) fixed the issue. Thank you!

It's because of floating point imprecision. The actual value of $value isn't just 7, it's 7.00000000000000088818. You can see that if you add the following line just after $value = (($price - $requestprice) / $price) * 100;:
printf("%.20f", $value);

Since 7.00000000000000088818 is greater than 7, the code is taking the right branch.

There's probably a PHP-specific dupetarget for this. Please ping me if you know one.
